# jqTouch Why is the ul not expanding?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, jqtouch

EDIT: this question is resolved thanks to a suggestion from @noShowP

I am filling an unordered list with *li*s that contains *a* after a ajax request. Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
li = $("<li><a val=\"" + $(this).parent().attr("id") + "\">" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>");
li.appendTo($("#subscriptions"));
```

The rows are being added, but the unordered list doesn't change its height. I can see in Firefox that the list items are added, but Firebug reports the height of the ul as being still 40px.

Here's the generated HTML according to firebug:

```
<ul id="subscriptions">
    <li><a val="s1" href="">subscription 1</a></li>
    <li><a val="s2" href="">subscription 2</a></li>
    <li><a val="s3" href="">subscription 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you got any styles on the ul?

Comment: I have the jqTouch apple theme, I am trying to build a simple, iphone style list.

Comment: @noShowP there was actually a style that was being applied and was changing the list, it was a style for an old element that had the same id, thank you, your question helped me find the problem!

Comment: Great, I was just in the midst of setting up my own test page and it was all working fine so was going to suggest you check any other styles you may have intefering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. noShowP was correct, there was a style that was disturbing the display.